# How to decode payload from modbus using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, node-red, modbus

I have a schneider power meter with rs485 surport. I using python with pymodbus to read register and decode payload from it (success). But now I want to do this with NodeJS, I can get raw data but I dont know how to decode it, I tried some method but result wrong!

This my python code:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient
from pymodbus.constants import Endian
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder

def validator(instance):
    if not instance.isError():
        '''.isError() implemented in pymodbus 1.4.0 and above.'''
        decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(
            instance.registers,
            byteorder=Endian.Big, wordorder=Endian.Little
        )   
        return float(decoder.decode_32bit_float())

    else:
        # Error handling.
        return None
validator([5658, 17242]) # Result is 218.1
```

When I use NodeJS it return buffer and i tried to decode with:

```
let buf = Buffer.from([0xd6, 0xd4, 0x42, 0x47]);

payload = buf.readFloatBE(0);   // It return other float number not 218.1
```

Can everyone help me ! Thanks !

Comment: An array containing a BigEndian float representing 218.1 would be `[0x43, 0x5a, 0x19, 0x9a]`

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong when copy buffer, I using node-red so it return  [5658, 17242] and buffer, with array i can decode with python but i cannot find same method with nodejs. :(

Comment: I wonder if it's because you have mixed big/little endian (byte vs word) in the python code

Comment: I moved 2 last item of buffer to start( [0xd6, 0xd4, 0x42, 0x47] => [0x42, 0x47, 0xd6, 0xd4]) then it True. Thank you! :D